# Difference between scanf and scanf_s in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, scanf, c11, tr24731

Although my program gives the required output. There are many warnings showing `scanf()` shouldn't be used and try using `scanf_s()` instead.

Possible cause of this warning??

This is happening to all the programs which are using the scanf function. Even simple addition of numbers.

Comment: What program? Post the relevant code!

Comment: Check this link https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081030175426AAWMnHi

Comment: Additionally, please check the documentation for these functions before asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `scanf`, with some format arguments it is possible to crash your program if you use unlimited size inputs. `scanf_s` requires to provide size of output buffers, thus limiting possibility of buffer overflows (provided you specify output buffer sizes correctly).